# Android MVVM - How to get an element from the XML to manipulate it and Where

Tags: java, android, mvvm, binding, architecture

I used to program in the conventional way for android without any architecture,
but i am trying to learn how to program with MVVM architecture in android.

They gave me a project with the architecture "ready" to start but it is taking me a bit to understand.

I understand the use of LiveData and MutableLiveData in the ViewModel layer, and the purpose of accessing it from the xml layout to manipulate the elements.
But, ***how can I access those elements to do things like give them an animation?***.

Example: IDLEMENT.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.top_animation);

Should I send the LoginBindingactivity from the View layer (LoginActivity) to the ViewModelLayer(LoginViewModel) ?

like this: loginViewModel.loginAnimation( activityLoginBinding) ? ,
and then do this in the ViewModel: activityLoginBinding.backgroundLayout.setAnimation(topAnim);?

***XML***

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="model"
        type="com.qsafeguardiaseguridad.viewmodel.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_login" />
</layout>
```

***View (LoginActivity)***

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//1) Inicio flujo en Activity
private LoginViewModel loginViewModel = null;
private ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    activityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    activityLoginBinding.setModel(loginViewModel);

    loginViewModel.loginAnimation( activityLoginBinding); //should i do this?
}
}
```

***ViewModel (LoginViewModel)***

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

public LoginViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
}

public LiveData<String> getUserLiveData(){
    return _userLiveData;
}
private final MutableLiveData<String> _userLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

private final MutableLiveData<String> _passwordLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
public LiveData<String> getPasswordLiveData(){
    return _passwordLiveData;
}

//variables animacion
Animation topAnim, bottomAnim;

/*Aquí también se manejan los eventos del Activity, en este caso
* un onclick del botón del inicio de sesión*/
public void loginButtonClicked(String user, String password){
    if(!user.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
        Log.w("Test",user+" "+password);
        LoginRepository.getToken(user, password, getApplication());

    }
}


//Should i do this?
public void loginAnimation(ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding){
    //Animations
    topAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.top_animation);
    bottomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.bottom_animation);
    activityLoginBinding.backgroundLayout.setAnimation(topAnim);
    activityLoginBinding.formLayout.setAnimation(topAnim);
    activityLoginBinding.versionName.setAnimation(bottomAnim);
}
}
```

Am I doing it right or wrong?

---

**UPDATE #1**

Trying to apply King's recommendation, should something like this be correct?

***View (LoginActivity)***

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//1) Inicio flujo en Activity
private LoginViewModel loginViewModel = null;
private ActivityLoginBinding activityLoginBinding = null;

//variables animacion
Animation topAnim, bottomAnim;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    activityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    loginViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    activityLoginBinding.setModel(loginViewModel);

    topAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.top_animation);
    bottomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.bottom_animation);
    activityLoginBinding.backgroundLayout.setAnimation(topAnim);
    activityLoginBinding.formLayout.setAnimation(topAnim);
    activityLoginBinding.versionName.setAnimation(bottomAnim);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No do not reference the View from the ViewModel;  the ViewModel is lifecycle aware.  The ViewModel keeps its state throughout the Activity’s lifecycle, but it’s essential to avoid any references to Views or Activities within a ViewModel because these (Views) throw a NullPointerException when destroyed. This will ultimately lead to a memory leak.

Animation should be carried out in then view layer, both Activity and Fragments are Views

1. you can do the animation in the main Activity
2. do the animation in a separate fragment i.e loginFragment

Comment: Thanks!, Could you give me feedback of my first update?

Comment: That is O.K as its in the view but a CLEANER way would be to navigate to a fragment that dose the animation then once it completes it will navigate to your initial activity. In MVVM you want your Activities to focus on handling lifecycle events.